# propiedad de objeto indefinida en angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, undefined, binding, interpolacion

tengo el siguiente problema y no hallo la forma de resolverlo. Tengo una interfaz, luego la importo e inicializo en un componente , pero cuándo intento asignar un valor a una de sus propiedades me dice que no está definida, cuál es el error? gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar con este problema.

dejo el código:

este es el componente padre

```js
  //para los textos
  textsPag1= {} as Texts;
  textsPag2= {} as Text;





  @ViewChild(PortadaComponent) coverPage: PortadaComponent;
  @ViewChild(Pag1Component) page1: Pag1Component;

  //Se subscribe a las imagenes de todas las paginas


  constructor(
    private uploadImgsService: UploadImagesService, 
    private usuarioService: UsuarioService,
    private productosService: ProductosService, 
    private ngZone: NgZone, private router: Router, 
    private dialog:MatDialog, 
    private snackBar: SnackBar

   ){ 
    // this.textsPag1.pag1Texts.text1= 'b'
    // this.textsPag1.pag1Texts.text2= 'b'
    // this.textsPag1.pag1Texts.text3= 'b'
    // this.textsPag1.pag1Texts.text4= 'b'
    // this.textsPag1.pag1Texts.text5= 'b'
```

acá llamo al hijo y le paso la variable textsPag1:

```js
    <div class="col">
        <app-portada [coverImages]="coverImages" [formData]="formData" [textsPag1]="textsPag1" *ngIf="cont == 1" [disabledClick]="disabledClick"> </app-portada>   <!-- modificar condicion del if, solo se dejó asi para prueba-->
        <app-pag1 [imagesPag2]="imagesPag2" [formData]="formData" [textsPag2]="textsPag2" [disabledClick]="disabledClick" *ngIf="cont == 2"> </app-pag1>
        <!-- <app-pag2 > </app-pag2>  -->
        
    </div>
```

este es el componente hijo:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-portada',
  templateUrl: './portada.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./portada.component.css']
})
export class PortadaComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

disabled: boolean= true;
@Input() coverImages: Images; 
@Input() formData: any;
@Input() coverTexts: Text;
@Input() textsPag1: Texts;
@Input() disabledClick: boolean;

  @ViewChild("fileInput1") el1: ElementRef;

  // coverImages= {} as Images;
  // data= {} as Text;
  test= {} as Texts;
  text1: string;
  disabledCl: any=null; // deshabilitar click
  form: any='';
  
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private usuarioService: UsuarioService, private uploadImgService: UploadImagesService) { 
    console.log('\n\nConstructor de PortadaComponent...')
    // this.textsPag1.pag1Texts.text1= 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ';
  }
```

la plantilla del componente hijo:

```html
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 no-gutters text-center ">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" style="width: 100%;">
        <div id="contPrincipal">
          <div id="img1" class="colorContCargaImg img" (click)="fileInput1.click()" [style.background-image]="'url(' + coverImages.img1 + ')'">
            <input #fileInput1 type="file" id="imageUpload1" accept=".png, .jpg, jpeg" name="file" (click)="Click($event)" (change)="uploadImg($event)">
          </div>
          <div id="img2" class="colorContCargaImg img"  >
            <textarea class="text-left textoNegro" [(ngModel)]="test.pag1Texts.text1"  ></textarea>
            
          </div>

          <div id="text1" class="colorContCargaImg img"  >
            <textarea class="text-left textoNegro" [(ngModel)]="test.pag1Texts.text2"  ></textarea>
            
          </div>

          <div id=text2 class="colorContCargaImg " >
            <textarea class="text-left textoBlanco" [(ngModel)]="test.pag1Texts.text3"  ></textarea>
              
          </div>          

          <div id=text3 class="colorContCargaImg " >
            <textarea class="text-center textoBlanco" [(ngModel)]="test.pag1Texts.text4" ></textarea>
              
          </div>          

          <div id=text4 class="colorContCargaImg textoBlanco"  > 
              <textarea class="text-center textoBlanco" [(ngModel)]="test.pag1Texts.text5" ></textarea>
          </div>          

          <div id=text5 class="colorContCargaImg img" >

          </div>

        </div>
        
      </div>
      
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

esta es la interfaz:

```js
export interface Texts {
    pag1Texts: {text1?: string, text2?: string, text3?: string, text4?: string, text5?: string  },
    pag2Texts: {text1?: string, text2?: string, text3?: string, text4?: string, text5?: string  },
    pag3Texts: {text1?: string, text2?: string, text3?: string, text4?: string, text5?: string  },
    pag4Texts: {text1?: string, text2?: string, text3?: string, text4?: string, text5?: string  },
    pag5Texts: {text1?: string, text2?: string, text3?: string, text4?: string, text5?: string  },
    pag6Texts: {text1?: string, text2?: string, text3?: string, text4?: string, text5?: string  },
    pag7Texts: {text1?: string, text2?: string, text3?: string, text4?: string, text5?: string  },
    pag8Texts: {text1?: string, text2?: string, text3?: string, text4?: string, text5?: string  },
    pag9Texts: {text1?: string, text2?: string, text3?: string, text4?: string, text5?: string  },
    pag10Texts: {text1?: string, text2?: string, text3?: string, text4?: string, text5?: string  },
    pag11Texts: {text1?: string, text2?: string, text3?: string, text4?: string, text5?: string  },
    pag12Texts: {text1?: string, text2?: string, text3?: string, text4?: string, text5?: string  },
    pag13Texts: {text1?: string, text2?: string, text3?: string, text4?: string, text5?: string  },
    pag14Texts: {text1?: string, text2?: string, text3?: string, text4?: string, text5?: string  }

}
```

acá dejo una captura del error en el componente portada (componente hijo):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se que es un problema de inicialización, pero no hallo como resolverlo, si ven en el componente padre hay unas lineas comentadas donde intente inicializar los valores antes de pasarlos al componente hijo pero no funcionó, como puedo arreglar esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valla te explico que estas haciendo, en la vista de hijo tienes lo siguiente a la altura de la linea 10.

```
  <div id="img2" class="colorContCargaImg img"  >
    <textarea class="text-left textoNegro" [(ngModel)]="test.pag1Texts.text1"  ></textarea>
    
  </div>
```

Acá estas diciendole al textarea que observe el valor de la variable **test.pag1Texts.text1**, entonces vamos a ver que tienes en el componente en la variable **test**

```
  // coverImages= {} as Images;
  // data= {} as Text;
  test= {} as Texts;  // <----- tienes test como un objeto que luego casteas Texts, jamás se implementa, intestas transformarlo
  text1: string;
  disabledCl: any=null; // deshabilitar click
  form: any='';
```

Tú al instanciar la variable **test** como = {} (implícitamente del tipo **any** y luego casteada a **Text** creas el objeto sin atributos ni nada, completamente en blanco y al castearlo a **Text** sigue en blanco, typescript no puede transformar ni va poder entender tu tipo **any** a **Text**) entonces cuando realizas la llamada al atributo pag1Texts de un tipo incorrecto que jamás fue instanciado.

ósea tu variable **test** se ve como la haz declarado {}, un objeto en blanco y al llamar al atributo **pag1Texts** obviamente te va dar undefined entonces:

```
test.pag1Texts = undefined
```

y ya sabes el resto, al llamar un atributo de un undefined obtienes un error, que es el que te muestra la consola.

Para solucionarlo tienes dos opciones:

1. Cambia de ***interface*** a ***class*** el tipo **Text**, y crea un constructor adecuado que pueda inicializar tus atributos. Creo que no es necesario un ejemplo, esto es bastante sencillo y te puede ahorrar muchos problemas.
2. Al objeto **test** asígnale el atributo **pag1Texts** en el constructor del componente, y este a su vez asígnale un valor tipo string al atributo **text1** ósea algo como esto.

```
// coverImages= {} as Images;
// data= {} as Text;
test= {} as Texts; // No necesitas hacer esto, me parece suficiente con que lo dejes como un any
text1: string;
disabledCl: any=null; // deshabilitar click
form: any='';

constructor(
 public dialog: MatDialog, 
 private usuarioService: UsuarioService, 
 private uploadImgService: UploadImagesService) { 
   console.log('\n\nConstructor de PortadaComponent...');
   // this.textsPag1.pag1Texts.text1= 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ';

   // Inicialización de lo que requiere tu vista componente PortadaComponent
   this.test.pag1Texts = {};
   this.test.pag1Texts.text1 = '';
}
```

Pienso que puedes optimizar tu código se ve un poco forzado, intenta siempre reutilizar en vez de declarar declarar y declarar.

Comment: Voy a intentarlo en unas horas ya que ya estoy durmiendo jeje. Se ve un poco forzado en qué sentido amigo?

Comment: podrías cambiar tu Interfaz a algo por el estilo, te va ayudar a entender mejor el código y reutilizar en x ocasiones:
`export class PageText {
  text: string[];
  constructor() {
   this.text = [];
  }
}

export class Texts {
  pagTexts: PageText [];
  constructor() {
   this.pagTexts = [];
  }
}`

--dale formato, en comentario no se puede.

Comment: cambie la implementación a clases, pero me sigue dando undefined.

Comment: Sí haz cambiado la implementación a class, y haz realizado un constructor adecuado dentro de la calss, cuando declaras la variables test debes hacer test: test = new Text(); trato de hacer un ejemplo en stackblitz, dame unos minutos.

Comment: Gracias, te lo agradezco. Aún ando con este problema.

Comment: [Ejemplo de la Opción 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uvvwvh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fportada-component%2Fportada-component.component.ts)
Acá te paso la solución de la Opción 2, te hago uno con la Opción 1 en un rato.
Observa el componente **./portada-componet/portada-component.component.ts** MIRA EL CONSTRUCTOR, he puesto las 2 líneas que agregue de la segunda opción de solución, si las retiras recibes el mensaje de que no se puede obtener el atributo de un undefined.

Comment: Ok, gracias, veo que para las demás text2, text3, no da error pero no están iniclializando en el constructor, esto a que se debe ?

Comment: el problema es que la variable que se interpola a la plantilla debe ser la misma que paso del padre al hijo, es decir, textsPag1 para que se vean los cambios cuando se actualiza desde el padre, la variable test la había colocado como una prueba de tantas que hice, estoy intendo hacer esto: ```this.textsPag1.pag1Texts = {}; this.textsPag1.pag1Texts.text1 = '';``` pero no funciona, dice ```ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'pag1Texts' of undefined``` .

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116057/discussion-between-julianprog-and-diego-1743).

Comment: pude usar lo que me dices pero en el ngOnChange, es lo que funcionó, si puedes me escribes al chat cuando tengas un tiempo, es este: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116057/discussion-between-julianprog-and-diego-1743  para hacerte una consulta y no seguir inundando esto de comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Los problemas que veo son los siguientes

1. En tu componente principal el código comentado

Declaraste: textsPag1= {} as Texts;   - puedes declararlo así también textsPag1: Texts= {}

En tu constructor:  // this.textsPag1.pag1Texts.text1= 'b'

Hasta this.textsPag1.pag1Texts esta bien porque angular automáticamente te va a crear el
valor pero quieres inicializar en un nulo // this.textsPag1.(aun no existe).text1= 'b'

Las correcciones serian las siguientes en tu constructor:
this.textsPag1.pag1Texts = {text1: "b", text2:"b", text3:"b"}

Comment: Hola amigo, esto creo que ya lo había intentado (entre tantos intentos que hice antes de hacer está pregunta) y no me funcionó.